# How to create a clip region from a path that includes the 'outline'?

Tags: winforms, system.drawing, region, graphicspath

I am creating a rounded rectangle GraphicsPath (see red outline image below), and then using this as a clip region both  when drawing graphics, and as the Region of a Form.

Unfortunately, although the path looks good, it doesn't work well as a region (see solid black image below)

Is there a way that I can generate a clipping region from the path that includes all the 'outline' pixels of the path? Do I need to generate a bitmap and then process this to create a region?

**The rounded rectangle path:**

[image: rounded rectangle]

**When used as a clip region:**

[image: clip region]

**The discrepancy (red pixels are in the path outline, but outside the region. blue pixels are in both):**

[image: overlap]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up drawing the shape into a bitmap and then converting this into a region.

[Here is an example of this.](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/graphicsandimages/article.php/c4259/Converting-Color-Keyed-Bitmaps-to-Custom-Regions.htm)